# Docker and DockerFile build

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile

I am a Docker Beginner and I have some trouble with Dockerfile build..and a lot of questions

Do I have to start command build in path /var/lib/docker/builder ?
How do I know that it does not build because my Dockerfile is not correct written?
Do I have to call my folder Dockerfile?

`docker build -t dokcerfile/xdebugphp .`

than i got
`Error response from daemon: unexpected error reading Dockerfile: read lstat /var/lib/docker/builder/Dokcerfile: no such file or directory`

with
`Get-Content Dockerfile | docker build -`

`Error response from daemon: the Dockerfile (Dockerfile) cannot be empty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch `docker build` from any directory.  If you try to `COPY` a file into an image that doesn't exist in the directory you name, you will see an error message that references `/var/lib/docker`, but that's an artifact of the Docker build implementation.  (In fact, you really shouldn't look inside or try to directly use the `/var/lib/docker` directory at all.)

The *file* containing the build instructions is conventionally named `Dockerfile` (on systems with case-sensitive filesystems, with a capital `D` and no extension).  It's most often located at the root of your source repository.  This shouldn't be a directory.

The `docker build -t` option assigns a tag (name) to the image that's built.  It doesn't have to correspond to a file on disk.  If you're using Docker Hub to store your images (or just want to emulate its naming) these have the form `username/imagename:version`; there is an extended format if you're using some other Docker image registry.

You can name the Dockerfile something else; if you do, you need the `docker build -f` option to reference that file.  If it's in a subdirectory of the repository root, the important detail is that `COPY` statements copy from the "context" directory you pass as the directory argument to `docker build`; this could be different from the directory that contains the Dockerfile.  For example, if your Dockerfile has `COPY index.php .`, and you run `docker build -f docker/xdebugphp .`, the file is copied from the `.` current directory, which is the parent directory of the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like line endings, try changing dockerfile line endings to LF

Also for Docker build command you need to be in the directory where the dockerfile is or specify the path to the dockerfile

so in the directory where dockerfile is command is
`docker build -t IMAGENAMEHERE .`

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it  with this command

```
docker build -t imagename -f Dockerfile/xdebugphp .
```